# No device logs output after attaching iPhone to process in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing iOS apps with Xcode. So when I build through Xcode I get device logs shown in the console output. But when I disconnect the iPhone from USB, or detach the process, then plug in the phone again and try to attach the process (my app is running on the phone still), the console doesn't output anything anymore.

If I go to Window -> Devices and my iPhone it doesn't show any output in that console either. The console app doesn't show any output either. I've tried to kill Xcode, clean the project, but to no success.

Anyone know how to show output logs from the built app after the iPhone have been detached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the log output mystery. Since we're using Cocoa Lumberjack it "devoured" the normal NSLog output, I added another log output by writing this row:

```
DEBUG_LOGS([DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance] withLevel:DDLogLevelDebug]);
```

Where DDASLLogger is the apple console.